# On Instagram, what is the heart number on a red label when I sign in?

Tags: notifications, instagram, analytics

Whenever I sign in on Instagram (desktop or mobile versions), numbers appear on a red label.

The one shaped like a head and shoulders usually means new people are following me since the last login. The one with a comment bubble means new comments since my last login.

But the one with the heart ***does not mean the number of likes since my last login***.

I have never seen the number be higher than 99, when most of my posts get around 50 likes in a few hours. This morning when I logged in the heart number was "**39**". I manually counted the likes for all 14 photos I posted yesterday and the total of likes is **421**.

[image]

**Is this a bug? What does this number mean?**

Answer (score 1):

It is a like counter, and it may or may not be buggy. Basically, these reasons can mess up the counter:

- It is possible when people who gave you like immediately unlike your photo. That’s the reason why you get the information of liking your photo but your post did not show the likes. It means people took back the likes before you check the notification hence you can see the notices without real likes.
- If you used tags, then tags attract likes from bots. These bots are deleted regularly by Instagram thus your likes may increase or decrease.
- There is something wrong from server side that means the Instagram system did not update the like number as well as the exact like list for your account. Because the like updating will not happen immediately after each like, it needs some time to gather the likes and update it on the post. Hence, it is better to wait a while to let Instagram update the likes number and get you the suitable number of likes on your post.
- Sometimes, Instagram shows out the virtual number of likes that is not an actual number of likes on your post. No matter what number is lower or higher than real likes number of your post, it will get back with real number soon with updating from Instagram.
- Not having an updated version of the app, or a fully updated browser if you are using Instagram in the browser.
- Getting too many likes in a short period of time. Instagram can't handle this sometimes.
- When you share an Instagram photo on Facebook, you essentially create an alternate universe of likes. Likes on your Facebook Timeline will be visible on Facebook, but they do not transfer over to Instagram, or vice versa. This basically means someone can like your Instagram photos without needing an Instagram account.
- It's a bug.

Answer (score -1):

First of all - congratulations on 421 likes! I have never had that many.. ever! lol

Basically it has to do with CQRS: Command Query Responsibility Segregation. Link to Microsoft page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cqrs

Reads and Writes are separated. Write events to the database take longer and are probably submitted via an event queue that gets processed eventually.
Reads are quicker. Instagram HAS to be able to serve Reads very quickly. It can't delay serving reels or posts, in order to preserve the user experience, so it can't combine Reads and Writes in the same pipe. Reads have to be handled separately.

In addition -
Instagram uses a distributed data storage architecture. Meaning - it will write a change to a Master node and this change will be reflected to all the Worker nodes eventually. While this process is happening, there is the possibility of your Instagram app client reading from a different Worker node to where the changes have not yet propagated, so it will not be current.

---

I am putting together an Instagram video on this subject. Below is my transcript for laypeople:

[Picture of notification feed]
Have you ever wondered why notifications about likes and comments show up HOURS late?
Or why something you Liked doesn't show up as having Liked it?
Or why if you switch to a different device you start seeing the same reels that you already saw before?
The reason is
Command
Query
Responsibility
Segregation

hard wipe
[Picture of pipes with reads flowing and writes flowing]
Commands are things like Likes and Comments that are Written to the Instagram database. These are called Write events.
Queries are Read events, when Instagram reads from its database to show you new reels and posts.

But Writes take longer than Reads.

[Picture of pipes with writes blocking reads]
We can't put writes in the same pipe with reads, otherwise it would slow everything down. It would take too long for people to be able to see new posts or reels.

So Writes have to happen in their own pipe.
[Picture of pipes with reads flowing and writes flowing]
Then, people can READ new posts and reels quickly, but WRITES, like likes and comments, will be delayed.

[Picture of speaker]
Not only that, but Instagram stores likes and comments in multiple places.

[Animation of dbs changing color]
That means, it writes to one place, called the Master, and later has to make sure all the other places, called the Workers, are consistent.
But this process takes HOURS.

After it's all done you get your notification that someone liked your story.

Now you know a little more about how Instagram works!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted since it is the correct answer and a very important part of how modern enterprise microservice architecture is built today. @Bot